# How to prove Θ(g(n)) = O(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n))

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, theory

I came across this statement, as per my understanding  Theta lies between Big O and Omega but I am unable to understand why intersection comes here. Can I get a mathematical as well as analytical understanding for  Θ(g(n)) = O(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Θ(g(n)) means that the function is bound both above and below by g(n).

Mathematically, if a function f(n) is Θ(g(n)), then

> *0   ≤   c<sub>1</sub>.g(n)  ≤  f(n)  ≤  c<sub>2</sub>.g(n)* for all n greater than some constant k

---

Now,

- O(g(n)) is upper bound on g(n), so a function that is O(g(n)) is upper bounded by g(n).
- Ω(g(n)) is lower bound on g(n), so a function that's Ω(g(n)) is lower bound by g(n).

`O(g(n)) ∩ Ω(g(n))` is representative of a function sandwiched between g(n) from both above and below, as shown in the image below, which by definition would be Θ(g(n)).

[image]

Mathematically, that means the function is *0 ≤ c<sub>1</sub>.g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>.g(n)*.